# What is the best practice for updating backends (REST, Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, architecture, software-design

Imagine you made a simple, monolithic REST backend with a database in the standard Spring Boot software stack. Arbitrary clients which you have no control over consume your REST endpoints. The database runs in a Docker container, the backend runs in a separate Docker container.

How do you handle updates to existing functionality with breaking changes? What do you do, when an existing data model (and database schema) changes and therefore the DTOs or the expected call format of the existing REST endpoints change?

It seems like this is to be expected in a project that is being actively developed while it's in productive use. But since you rolled out a version already, you must support it (at least for a while). Do you version your endpoints in some way? If so, how is it done? Do you keep multiple instances (at least one per version) of the application running and somehow hope they can all access the database properly? However, every version should still use the same database.

Are there any best practices for this or am I making up a problem that does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Updates like the ones you described happen all the time in production systems.
You may decide to follow one of these strategies:

**1. Update your API and all the clients at the same time.** Depending on how many users you have and how much control you have on their systems, you may be able to schedule with them when the new API is going to be released and when they'll need to start using a new client. In this case, it's essential that you provide documentation for the newer version of your API and possibly a test environment for your users to try their new clients.

**2. Split your breaking change into several non-breaking steps.** This is normally achieved by releasing a version of your API that supports the old and the new format first. You could distinguish between the two by having a different URL or requiring a different parameter (such as version=2). Once all your users had the chance of upgrading their clients, you can drop support of your old version.

With both these strategies, it is critical that you announce the change and communicate with your users, providing enough notice and enough information about the new API.

Answer (score 0):

If its really necessary to change an existing endpoint you should document, it in your changelog and maybe also make an extra node in you Documentation that something has changes in Version X.X
If you can avoid a change with a new endpoint, I would suggest this.

This problem does exist, that's why it's good to carefully plan you API beforehand :)